# Ubuntu Tile Server, tile generation for specific area(country)

Tags: render, openstreetmap, tiles, mapnik

I built a tile server on **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** using [this.](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/) It works fine.

*Short intro how it works:*

> When a request is thrown on **apache**, it sends the request to
>   **renderd** and **mapnik**. If tile doesn't exist for those coordinates, it renders(creates) on-the-fly needed tiles, and saves it to tile
>   folder using .meta extension, so next time when a request comes, it
>   wont re-render if tile already exsits, it just servers the existing
>   tile in file system.

*Problem:*

> When multiple requests are thrown, **mapnik** and **renderd** most of
>   the time they need to render(create) tiles, because they don't exist. It takes long time
>   sometimes, few seconds before loading map in specific areas.

*Question:*

> I know there is some workaround for this, for example using:
>   render_list, to pre-render tiles, but I couldn't understand how to use
>   it, and how to give it parameters so it will generate tiles for a
>   specific country only(the one my map is used the most).

Comment: The Internets has lots of examples how to use render_list, one is at [gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29287/using-render-list-to-render-only-map-extract) which is also a way better place to ask your question.